# Show difference image for PageOrientation.LandscapeRight by clicking the emulator button

Tags: windows-phone-7

The page starts as "Partrait" and I have code to catch the orientation change for adjust the user controls.  I don't figure out why showing difference on the same code by changing the order to press the button on emulator to roated the screen. The following is my code to catch the orienation change event.

```
 if (previousOrientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp && e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
        {
            this.LayoutRoot.Width = 730;
            lst.lst.Height = 220;
            lst.lst.Width = 730;
            this.LayoutRoot.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
            this.TitlePanel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 65, 0);


        }
        if (e.Orientation.ToString().Contains("Portrait"))
        {
            this.LayoutRoot.Width = 480;
            this.LayoutRoot.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
            lst.lst.Height = 400;
            lst.lst.Width = 450;
            this.TitlePanel.Margin = new Thickness(12, 0, 40, 0);
            this.TitlePanel.Margin = new Thickness(12, 17, 2, 0);

        }
```

when I pressed second time on the first button on the emulator to rotate the screen, (`previousOrientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp && e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight`) is fired. It shows the big application bar's background yellow color.

If I pressed first time on the second button on the emulator to rotate the screen, the same line "(`previousOrientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp && e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight`)" is fired. It shows the narrow application bar's background yellow color that I wanted.

Since I am a new user, I cannot upload the image. If you are interested on my question, I can send the image to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "second time on the first button" and "first time on the second button" .. I ddnt understand that. But your code is working fine as expected. Elaborate your problem a bit

Comment: @nkchandra, the first button on emulator rotates the screen on left hand side. the sceond button rotates the phone on right hand side. Although the code is same (fire on previousOrientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp && e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight), the display is difference.

Comment: So where are you updating the previousOrientation field's value ?

Comment: @nkchandra, I update it on Orientationchanged event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I serached the forums @ the following website. It seems it is the bug.

[Application Bar resizes after rotation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/1145e5be-2d4c-4517-9948-5ce88cb15ed8)